# Why is restored database faster than original?

Tags: postgresql, backup, postgresql-performance, postgresql-13

I ran this `explain analyse` in my PostgreSQL 13.7 database:

```
explain(analyze, verbose, buffers, settings) select * from main_table;
 Seq Scan on public.main_table  (cost=0.00..10246.15 rows=220715 width=687) (actual time=0.015..168.565 rows=220287 loops=1)
   Output: id, name, ...
   Buffers: shared hit=7243 read=796
 Planning Time: 0.139 ms
 Execution Time: 178.958 ms
```

The execution time is always between 160 and 200 ms.

I've dumped and restored the database in same machine and repeated the `explain`:

```
explain(analyze, verbose, buffers, settings) select * from main_table;
 Seq Scan on public.main_table  (cost=0.00..10198.86 rows=220286 width=689) (actual time=0.049..41.595 rows=220286 loops=1)
   Output: id, name, ...
   Buffers: shared read=7996
 Planning Time: 0.128 ms
 Execution Time: 51.647 ms
```

The execution time is always between 45 and 55 ms.

Why is the restored DB faster than the original? I executed `VACUUM FULL` and `reindex database` in original database, but execution time doesn't change. Can I do anything else?

**NEW TEST WITH track_io_timing ON**

I ran `explain analyse` three times in each database

ORIGINAL

```
 Seq Scan on public.main_table  (cost=0.00..10275.46 rows=221346 width=687) (actual time=0.025..181.509 rows=220527 loops=1)
   Output: id, name,...
   Buffers: shared hit=6355 read=1707
   I/O Timings: read=7.113
 Planning:
   Buffers: shared hit=318 read=60 dirtied=1
   I/O Timings: read=8.793
 Planning Time: 10.500 ms
 Execution Time: 191.809 ms
 
  Seq Scan on public.main_table  (cost=0.00..10275.46 rows=221346 width=687) (actual time=0.028..183.451 rows=220527 loops=1)
   Output: id, name,...
   Buffers: shared hit=328 read=7734
   I/O Timings: read=24.171
 Planning:
   Buffers: shared hit=314 read=64
   I/O Timings: read=0.859
 Planning Time: 2.411 ms
 Execution Time: 193.878 ms


 Seq Scan on public.main_table  (cost=0.00..10275.46 rows=221346 width=687) (actual time=0.048..174.678 rows=220527 loops=1)
   Output: id, name,...
   Buffers: shared hit=456 read=7606
   I/O Timings: read=21.949
 Planning Time: 0.289 ms
 Execution Time: 184.883 ms
```

RESTORED

```
 Seq Scan on public.main_table  (cost=0.00..10198.86 rows=220286 width=689) (actual time=1.199..277.902 rows=220286 loops=1)
   Output: id, name,...
   Buffers: shared read=7996
   I/O Timings: read=252.057
 Planning:
   Buffers: shared hit=341 read=40
   I/O Timings: read=33.752
 Planning Time: 35.319 ms
 Execution Time: 288.698 ms
 
  Seq Scan on public.main_table  (cost=0.00..10198.86 rows=220286 width=689) (actual time=0.107..47.826 rows=220286 loops=1)
   Output: id, name,...
   Buffers: shared hit=32 read=7964
   I/O Timings: read=26.934
 Planning Time: 0.140 ms
 Execution Time: 58.268 ms

 Seq Scan on public.main_table  (cost=0.00..10198.86 rows=220286 width=689) (actual time=0.058..42.252 rows=220286 loops=1)
   Output: id, name,...
   Buffers: shared read=7996
   I/O Timings: read=22.246
 Planning Time: 0.127 ms
 Execution Time: 51.822 ms
```

**NEW TEST WITH ISOLATED DATABASE**

I have now a isolated database without connections. I've restarted postgres before start with the tests. All tests are over same instance.

```
original=# vacuum full;
VACUUM

original=# reindex database original;
REINDEX

original=# explain(analyze, verbose, buffers, settings) select * from main_table;
 Seq Scan on public.main_table  (cost=0.00..10379.26 rows=223526 width=689) (actual time=0.127..178.371 rows=223526 loops=1)
   Output: id, name, ...
   Buffers: shared hit=352 read=7792
   I/O Timings: read=27.463
 Planning Time: 0.172 ms
 Execution Time: 188.395 ms
```

After I've created a copy from psql console

```
postgres=# create database restored template = original;
restored=# explain(analyze, verbose, buffers, settings) select * from main_table;
 Seq Scan on public.main_table  (cost=0.00..10379.26 rows=223526 width=689) (actual time=0.210..178.115 rows=223526 loops=1)
   Output: id, name, ...
   Buffers: shared hit=96 read=8048
   I/O Timings: read=20.545
 Planning Time: 0.195 ms
 Execution Time: 188.460 ms
```

It's a normal result, all values are the same. Then I've created a copy from linux console

```
/tmp$ pg_dump original > backup.psql
/tmp$ dropdb restored
/tmp$ createdb restored
/tmp$ psql restored < backup.psql

restored=# explain(analyze, verbose, buffers, settings) select * from main_table;
 Seq Scan on public.main_table  (cost=0.00..10349.26 rows=223526 width=687) (actual time=0.194..41.564 rows=223526 loops=1)
   Output: id, name, ...
   Buffers: shared hit=383 read=7731
   I/O Timings: read=20.332
 Planning Time: 0.193 ms
 Execution Time: 51.556 ms
```

Now the number of rows is the same, but width is less.

Any ideas? Can I launch some more tests to find out why the execution time is less on the restored database?

**IMPORTANT TEST OVER SAME DATABASE**

I saw main_table has two dropped columns...

```
original=# SELECT attnum, attname, attisdropped
         FROM pg_attribute a
         JOIN pg_class c ON c.oid = a.attrelid
         WHERE c.relname = 'main_table'
               AND c.relkind = 'r'
               AND a.attnum > 0 AND attisdropped = 't';
 attnum |            attname            | attisdropped
--------+-------------------------------+--------------
     34 | ........pg.dropped.34........ | t
     45 | ........pg.dropped.45........ | t
```

Then I've copied the table and launch explain...

```
original=# create table test (like main_table INCLUDING ALL);
CREATE TABLE
original=# INSERT INTO test select * from main_table;
INSERT 0 223526
original=# explain(analyze, verbose, buffers, settings) select * from test;
 Seq Scan on public.test  (cost=0.00..10349.26 rows=223526 width=689) (actual time=0.007..29.275 rows=223526 loops=1)
   Output: id, name, ...
   Buffers: shared hit=8114
 Planning:
   Buffers: shared hit=296 dirtied=36
 Planning Time: 0.795 ms
 Execution Time: 39.383 ms
```

Surprise! Execution time is perfect! Maybe the dropped columns hinders performance? I don't know, but it sounds weird

Comment: this belongs on [dba.se]

Comment: Did you try `VACUUM FULL` on the original database? Rewriting all tables to optimize storage. When you use explain, please use `explain(analyze, verbose, buffers, settings)` to get the whole picture, including memory usage etc.

Comment: Check this out: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/335749/performce-problems-on-parallel-seq-scan

Comment: @FrankHeikens I executed vacuum full and reindex database, but the execution time doesn't change it

Comment: Turn on track_io_timing on both instances, then repeat the plans on both instances.

Comment: @jjanes in the first explain, I can see a value but after, it is not shown

Comment: If there are no reads, it not show a timing.  What is the timing for the one it does show?

Comment: It's odd that neither the number of rows, nor their width is identical. Makes me doubt your comparison.

Comment: @jjanes I ran the explain again and now we have new values. I've copied in main post

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter Original database is alive because it is a production database and "restored" is a yesterday's backup. For the tests, I've stopped frontend and databases were without connections

Comment: Is the restore done into a different instance (e.g. running on a different port), or just into a different database of the same instance?  If the first, then are their any long-open sessions on the slow one which might be holding snapshots and preventing hint bits from getting set?

Comment: @jjanes it is same instance. From console with postgres user I do pg_dump original > backup.sql, createdb test, psql test < backup.sql. Then, I connect it and launch explain

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter I've launched tests in a isolated database. Number of rows are now identical but width is not

Answer (score 1):

You added insightful findings about dropped columns later. That might explain *some* of the performance difference. But normally, 99 % of that would be covered by `VACUUM FULL`, without having to create a new table (or database for that matter).

Dropping a column is a very fast operation in Postgres. The entry in the system catalog `pg_attribute` is not removed, just marked with `attisdropped`. (Depending objects are dropped, like indexes or FK references.) This avoids a time-consuming table-rewrite, renumbering attributes, etc., so it can be very fast. Physical storage of table rows is unchanged, the columns is invisible for future queries, but still occupies space. See:

- [Dropping column in Postgres on a large dataset](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15700213/939860)

`VACUUM FULL` (or `CLUSTER`, or community tools like pg_squeeze or pg_repack) physically rewrite the table in pristine condition, removing all bloat. Zombi values from dropped columns are replaced with `null` in the process, which occupies a single bit in the null bitmap.  (One might argue that `VACUUM FULL` should clean out dropped columns. But it's just not implemented.) Normally, that covers 99 % of any possibly impact zombi columns might have.

There are corner cases. Dropping columns routinely could pile up zombis. (And we all know from the movies how that can become a threat where a few zombis are harmless. So avoid that.) But you reported **two dropped columns**. Should barely even matter *after* `VACUUM FULL`.

The worst case imaginable would be a table of 7 boolean columns. The null bit map would be "for free". See:

- [Do nullable columns occupy additional space in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12147130/939860)

Two dropped columns would bring the number up to 9 and force allocation of 8 bytes for every row. Storage size without zombis: 4 + 24 + 8 = 36 bytes, Storage size with zombis: 4 + 24 + 8 + 8 = 44 bytes. Even that, while making  a notable difference, wouldn't come close to explaining the 4-5 fold speedup you report.

I am puzzled how rewriting the table could have such a big impact where `VACUUM FULL` did not. Are you sure you did run `VACUUM FULL` to completion in your tests?

---

Aside, the observed variation in the estimated row width can be caused by variable-size columns (like `varchar` or `jsonb`, ...). Column statistics are built by `ANALYZE` (or `autovacuum`) based on a random sample and can show fluctuation in this case.

Comment: Are zombie columns the reason for poor performance? we don't know. We just know if I create new table from select, performance is good, but I can wipe another problem that the original table had. Yes, I launch vacuum full in my tests. If you have more tests, we can investigate this futher.